# Jenkins get first "word" from each line of command output

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-groovy

For our pipeline we want to use the output of a command:
Example:

```
 script {
        def command_output = sh(returnStdout: true, script: """some command """).trim()
        def command_output_two = sh(returnStdout: true, script: """some_other_command ${command_output} """).trim()
        
}
```

The command output looks lile:

```
property:onetwo some comments
value:onetwo not interest in the last part
property:five some comments
```

I want to convert the output to contain only the first part of each line before the first space. Everything after the first space should be ignored, and all added in one line, so it can be used for the next command.

```
property:onetwo value:onetwo property:five
```

Is there a proper jenkins way to do it? e.g. after I get the command output use some jenkins methods, or should I add something to the command e.g. a grep command with a regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an oneliner for your use-case.

```
def formattedString = command_output.readLines().collect { it.split().head() }.join(" ")

println(formattedString)
```

Comment: What does the split().head() part do, does it split by default on space, and than head for the first value?

Comment: @SvenvandenBoogaart Yes, `split()` splits the string by space by default and `head()` gets the first element from the array of split elements.

Answer (score 0):

Created a function, where I loop over all lines, and than split by space and take the first match.

```
def getInSingleLine(String input_list){
    def lines = new String( input_list).split( '\n' )
    def single_string_value = ""
    lines.each { item ->
        single_string_value += " " + getFirstWord(item)
    }
    return single_string_value
}

def getFirstWord(String text) {
    text = text.trim()
    int index = text.indexOf("\t");
    if (index > -1) { 
        return text.substring(0, index).trim();
    } else {
        return text; // no match found, return full word.
    }
}
```